# Change WPF browser version

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I know this question is asked many times and solution to this is adding key to registry as below.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
   SOFTWARE
      Microsoft
         Internet Explorer
            Main
               FeatureControl
                  FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
                     contoso.exe = (DWORD) 11001
```

but I can't do that since many of user of application don't run under administrator privileges. So I need a solution without touching registry. I already got one but it changes render mode instead of browser version.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

this meta tag directly under `<head>` will do that. But problem is, in `WPF` window it's design is different than one in `IE11`.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: You don't need admin rights to write to HKEY_CURRENT_USER. So just write there and done.

Comment: @Anonymous or you need installation process that runs as administrator and can update `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. You only need to do it once for each exe